# Extra Chunks From Rollup bundling Sapper

Tags: javascript, svelte, rollup, sapper, svelte-3

Base on the Sapper documentation, Rollup bundles Sapper by pages. It should be one chunk per page. However, in our situation, there is more than one chunk per page. Some of the components and utility functions (not all of them, not none of them, but some) got bundled into its individual chunk.

For example with the screenshot below, **AdBanner** and **TextExpander** are components within the sapper page, but they got bundled into their own js files rather than being with the sapper page js file **index.27bfb559.js**.

However, looking at the sapper page js file **index.27bfb559.js**, **SimilarDrugTable** is bundled with the sapper page js file.

Essentially, what we want to achieve is one chunk per page like Sapper documentation states.

[image]

Comment: Are `AdBanner` and `TextExpander` used in more than one place? That would explain them being moved into their own chunks. Otherwise, that code would have to be duplicated in each of the places they were used

Comment: @RichHarris Yup, your guess is correct. Thank you!

Comment: @RichHarris however, we have some components that are also used in more than one place, yet not being bundle as its individual chunk. Do you have any theory?

Comment: If `/a` and `/b` both depend on `<C>` and `<D>` (and nothing else does), you'll get a CD chunk rather than a C chunk and a D chunk. That's the most likely explanation.